# Why does "about:blank" tabs open up in Chrome every time I search in Unity's sidebar, even before pushing enter?

Tags: 13.04, google-chrome, search, google

Ubuntu 13.04, Google Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110

I assume it's related to a program I have installed via apt-get, but not sure which.

As I am typing, while it is doing the "auto-completion" searching, windows keep popping up, even if Chrome is closed.